# how to fetch file size in sql

Tags: sql

I have created a store procedure in the SQL server and in that process, we are doing data ingestion with CSV files from my development server and we need a file size so how to get the file size?

Comment: You mean the file size of the CSV file? If yes, it does not relate to SQL Server at all.

Comment: create SQLCLR function to get file size

Comment: I would recommend to use a Python Script to ingest the CSV Data. You can get all information of the file that way.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.